# Evaluate the limit using Sandwich Theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}(3^{x} + 1)^{1/x} = ?$$

I tried several things like introducing $3^{1/x^{2}}$ as it's limit as $x \to \infty$ is $1$. I just need a hint.

(Excuse my lack of 'latex' proficiency)

Comment: Use the fact that $3^{x} < 3^{x} + 1 < 2\cdot 3^{x}$ for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the sandwich theorem we need a function $f$ and a function $g$ which fulfill three criteria:

1. Their limits as $x\to \infty$ are relatively easy to compute.
2. Their limits are equal.
3. $f(x)\leq (3^x+1)^x\leq g(x)$ for all $x$, at least all large enough $x$.

The function $f(x)=(3^x)^{1/x} =3$ is an obvious choice. You need to find a $g(x)$ and the proposed $(2\cdot 3^x)^{1/x}$ works nicely.